# Check whether web page exist on the web or not

Tags: java, web-applications, jsoup

I am currently using Jsoup to parse HTML document and I use the following command to get the document first

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).post();
```

if URL is not a real or existing URL, then error message will appear. So, is there any way to check that and print error message

thanks,
Zhua

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a URL exists or returns 404 with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378199/how-to-check-if-a-url-exists-or-returns-404-with-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will throw an exception?

Probablly so. Why not put it in a try, and check for that kind of exception?
sth like

```
try{
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).post();
    // it gets here, when it works
}   catch(InvalidUrlException e){
    //bla bla bla...
}
```

it seems easy to do so.

Comment: thanks for replying! But I cannot find a class that I need to import to the application because it gives me error when using InvalidUrlException . It says cannot find symbol :class InvalidUrlException

Comment: funny, i didn't know the precise name of exception, i just wrote "InvalidUrlException". Try java.net.MalformedURLException. Or simply Exception, and see what message it contains.