# GWT: Check if URL is dead

Tags: java, url, gwt

I'm trying to check if a url (in String form) returns 404 error. However, I can't seem to use java.net.URL, and I read somewhere that java.net is not supported in GWT? If so, how do I check if URL is dead or not in GWT?

Much appreciated.

Comment: This was already answered in this SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378199/how-to-check-if-a-url-exists-or-returns-404-with-java

Comment: Roflcoptr, that question did not concern GWT client-side inquiry. So is not duplicated by this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. In client side GWT you cannot use java.net.URL. Take a look at [Google's JRE Emulation Reference](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) if you are unsure what parts of the Java standard library can be uses with GWT.

Theoretically it would be possible to check a URL with an AJAX request (see [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html)). But due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) it is likely that the browser prevents such an attempt.

So I think you should implement the check on your applications server side (according to the link provided by Roflcoptr above in the comments) and call that routine with [GWT-RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html).

Comment: gotcha, I'm going to try adding that to the server side. Thanks!

Comment: Jin, I think you should also flag the answer +1, besides flagging it as accepted answer. BTW, that +1 was mine, now's your turn.