# ANDROID - can not connect to website

Tags: android, jsoup

I try to connect a website to parse some elements with `JSOUP`.

This is error log

```
    12-01 17:34:24.938 591-870/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 4816
12-01 17:34:54.947 591-870/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 4817
12-01 17:35:24.946 591-870/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 4818
12-01 17:35:44.655 2856-2856/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-01 17:35:44.655 2856-2856/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-01 17:35:45.136 591-709/? E/PackageManager: parse pkg : /data/app/vmdl926348494.tmp
12-01 17:35:45.156 591-2879/? E/PackageManager: dexopt start
12-01 17:35:49.060 591-2879/? E/PackageManager: dexopt end
12-01 17:35:49.901 4527-4527/? E/SamsungIME: mOCRHelper is null
12-01 17:35:49.901 4527-4527/? E/SamsungIME: mOCRHelper is null
12-01 17:35:51.882 2919-2919/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-01 17:35:51.882 2919-2919/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-01 17:35:52.183 975-975/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
12-01 17:35:52.183 975-975/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
12-01 17:35:52.693 2956-2973/ytu.ytu2 E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
12-01 17:35:52.693 2956-2973/ytu.ytu2 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: ytu.ytu2, PID: 2956
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ytu.ytu2/ytu.ytu2.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at ytu.ytu2.MainActivity.connect(MainActivity.java:57)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at ytu.ytu2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
12-01 17:35:52.923 2956-2956/ytu.ytu2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
12-01 17:35:53.284 591-2999/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -m 2956 -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
12-01 17:35:54.945 591-870/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 4819
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter: Error acquiring lock: /data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_state_logs/e9d2c7b4-fcc2-42a5-a2d9-e57277e8cb06.txt
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter: java.io.IOException: fcntl failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.basicLock(FileChannelImpl.java:123)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:177)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:587)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.a(AppStateReporter.java:141)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.c(AppStateReporter.java:94)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.a(AppStateReporter.java:55)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer.a(NonCriticalInitializer.java:103)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer$2.run(NonCriticalInitializer.java:116)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.appchoreographer.DefaultAppChoreographer$5.run(DefaultAppChoreographer.java:384)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(WrappingExecutorService.java:77)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.executors.DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService.java:327)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:42)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:  Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: fcntl failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at libcore.io.Posix.fcntlFlock(Native Method)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.fcntlFlock(ForwardingOs.java:54)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.basicLock(FileChannelImpl.java:121)
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:177) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:587) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.a(AppStateReporter.java:141) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.c(AppStateReporter.java:94) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.a(AppStateReporter.java:55) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer.a(NonCriticalInitializer.java:103) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer$2.run(NonCriticalInitializer.java:116) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.appchoreographer.DefaultAppChoreographer$5.run(DefaultAppChoreographer.java:384) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(WrappingExecutorService.java:77) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.executors.DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService.java:327) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:42) 
12-01 17:35:57.178 2986-3077/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
12-01 17:35:57.638 975-975/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
12-01 17:35:57.638 975-975/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
12-01 17:35:58.389 157-396/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
12-01 17:35:58.389 157-396/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
12-01 17:36:00.911 3288-3288/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.speech.tts.Voice', referenced from method com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onGetVoices
```

This line 57:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
```

this 49

```
 connect();
```

Calling connect method to make a connection.

[check for validity of URL in java. so as not to crash on 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816559/check-for-validity-of-url-in-java-so-as-not-to-crash-on-404-error)

i tried the suggestion here but did not work. AS soon as screen cmes, it crashes with toast `it is stopped`

Maybe i can use another thing instead of jsoup but i did some codes inside eclipse in java so i dont know if i can migrate them, for example okhttp.

This is my code. most of imports are useless.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;


import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;



  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      String URL="https://stackoverflow.com/";
      Document doc;
      String html;//from page, parsed part



public static TextView textView;
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          textView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txt);
        //  textView.setText(" coor ");
       //   WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(getActivity());

          connect();
          }



public void connect (){

          try {
              doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
              textView.append(" con ");
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();textView.append(" catch ");
          }
         // html = doc.select("script").get(10).toString();
        //  textView.append(" selected ");
      }


              }
```

Comment: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` That's your issue. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: but i want to parse the things i found to textview. How can i parse from that class for example after each methot execute i want to see if it is worked or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not do that connection in the main thread. You must use another thread or implement an Async class to do that. Android avoid the use of the mainThread to make connections in order that the UI does not get freezed.

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: but main class extends activity. how to extend async too?

Comment: implement it in an inner class. There are tons of examples over there

Comment: hello sir.any alternatives except async and thread? for example from onclick, call anotjher method than call connect?

Comment: you can call an async task inside an onClick event. This kind of connections NEVER can be done in the main thread. You can create another thread when you do a click too.