# URL 404 Checker for bash

Tags: bash, http, url, header, http-status-code-404

I want to write some code i can run in the bash that takes a list of URL's and checks if they return a 404. If the site is not returning a 404 i need the url to be written to the output list.

So in the end i should have a list with working sites.
I do not know how to realize the code.
This looks like something that could work right?:
**[How to check if a URL exists or returns 404 with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378199/how-to-check-if-a-url-exists-or-returns-404-with-java)**

Comment: something like:
if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "list of url's"
then
       "write to example.txt"

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code and build on it as necessary:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( "http://www.stackoverflow.com" "http://www.google.com" )

for url in "${array[@]}"
do
    if ! curl -s --head  --request GET ${url} | grep "404 Not Found" > /dev/null
    then
       echo "Output URL not returning 404 ${url}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'd just add that you may not want to grep on "404". This can lead to weird edge cases, such as when 404 is in the MD5 hash returned by curl. I suggest grepping on "404 Not Found". Other than that your example works perfectly.

Comment: @aeskreis I modified the grep as you suggested.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Removing the ! would make this work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I found a package for linux called linkchecker. It does exactly what i want.

Comment: glad I could help in some way.  If you don’t mind please check off my answer as accepted. Thx.

Comment: [`linkchecker`](https://linkchecker.github.io/linkchecker/) URL. `--check-extern` also check URLs that point to external domains